# multiple submit widgets, detecting which button was activated

Tags: dojo

I'm using dojo 1.9. I have a form with 2 submit buttons, and I want to detect which button was activated, causing the form submit event.

In the api, I found that widgets have a `focused` property that seems to be true when they are clicked, or when the enter key was pressed when it has focus.

Does dojo provide something in their api to detect which button(or form control) caused the form submit? My method seems to work, but I'd feel more comfortable using something intended for this. My first idea was to check the submit event object and look at the srcElement, but dojo seems to have this always set to the form element

I made a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YRz8N/1/) showing what I tried.

html

```
<form id="prefs-form">
    <div>
        <input id="name">
        <button id="save" type="button">Save</button>
        <button id="delete" type="button">Delete</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

js

```
require(["dijit/form/Button", "dijit/form/TextBox", "dijit/form/Form", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Button, TextBox, Form){

    var saveBtn = new Button({
        type: 'submit',
    }, "save");

    //make delete button
    var deleteBtn = new Button({
        type: 'submit'
    }, "delete");


    var textBox = new TextBox({
    }, "name");

    var form = new Form({
        onSubmit: function(evt){
            dojo.stopEvent(evt);
            console.log(saveBtn.get("focused"));
            console.log(deleteBtn.get("focused"));
            console.log(textBox.get("focused"));
        }
    }, "prefs-form");    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making submit buttons, just make regular buttons, wire to the onclick event on the button, do what you need and then submit the form programmatically.

```
on(saveBtn, 'click', function(evt) {
    console.log('save');
    form.submit(); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/uNusq/